# Verify fails even when method gets called

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I'm testing the below code, however the test case is failing. Line 23 gives InvocationTargetException. Is there any issue on returning a mock if a certain other mock's method is called?

Moreover, even if I comment line 23, line 26 below again fails the `verify`. Turning on the debugger throws the InvocationTargetException. I'm just checking whether the `fetchSideThing` method is called once or not. How can I do that?

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SideThing {
    int weight;

    SideThing(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public static SideThing get(int w) {
        return new SideThing(w);
    }
}

public class ThingGrandParent {

    int tgpVal;
    ThingGrandParent(int val) {
        tgpVal = val;
    }

    public ThingParent GpFun(int y) {
        return new ThingParent(y);
    }
}

public class ThingParent {

    SideThing st;

    ThingParent(int x) {
        st = new SideThing(x);
    }

    public SideThing fetchSideThing() {
        return st;
    }

    private int anotherFun(int y) {
        return y;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Thing {
    private int size;
    private int name;

    Thing() {}

    int bLogic(int size) throws Exception {
        ThingGrandParent tgp = fun(size);
        SideThing st;

        ThingParent tp = tgp.GpFun(size);
        st = tp.fetchSideThing();
        return st.getWeight();
    }

    public ThingGrandParent fun(int size) {
        return new ThingGrandParent(size);
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@PrepareForTest({Thing.class, SideThing.class})
public class ThingTest {

    @Mock
    ThingParent tp;
    @Mock
    ThingGrandParent tgpp;


    Thing t;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       t = spy(new Thing()); // does it matter here if `t` is an InjectMocks or a spy?
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        when(tgpp.GpFun(anyInt())).thenReturn(tp); // -- line23, why InvocationTargetException?

        assertEquals(4, t.bLogic(4));

        verify(tp, times(1)).fetchSideThing(); //-- line26 InvocationTargetException
    }
}
```

Also, as indicated in the code, does it really make any sort of difference if I use spy or InjectMocks for `Thing t`?

I've used `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in the `setup()`, but it says that 'initMocks(java.lang.Object)' is deprecated. What else should I use here then?

Here's the failure message:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
tp.fetchSideThing();
-> at com.amazon.configurationeditor.store.ThingTest.test1(ThingTest.java:62)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
tp.fetchSideThing();
-> at com.amazon.configurationeditor.store.ThingTest.test1(ThingTest.java:62)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.amazon.configurationeditor.store.ThingTest.test1(ThingTest.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: You need to add the full exception stack trace to your question

Comment: Problem with the exception originates in the fact, that t is never used in any of your test routines. It is just there, never to be used, thus the exception. As in my answer already described is a necessary change to overcome it. ``when(t.fun(anyInt()).thenReturn(tgpp)``

Comment: @MJG `t` is a spy, I don't think how when-thenReturn will work here :(

Comment: It does! simple to prove: ```   Object x = new Object();
   @Test
   void testX() throws IOException {

      final Object spy = Mockito.spy(x);
      when(spy.toString()).thenReturn("I spy");
      System.out.printf("spy: %s%n", spy);
   }```

Comment: @MJG, I added the `doReturn(tgpp).when(t).fun(anyInt());` and debugged that `tgp` in `ThingGrandParent tgp = fun(size);` is now getting mocked but however, I see that `tp` in `ThingParent tp = tgp.GpFun(size);` is coming out to be a null value. I tried adding `when(tgpp.GpFun(anyInt())).thenReturn(tp);` but it throws some exception - `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: ThingParent$MockitoMock$1585543497`

Comment: Did you try to move the doReturn(tgpp) to a location that is executed where tgpp is *not* `null`. I.e. inside the `test1`.

Comment: Yes inside test1 as the first statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249354/discussion-between-mjg-and-ajay-negi).

Comment: You have mock instances of ThingParent and ThingGrandParent, but those instances are never used in your test. You classes are creating new instances.

Answer (score 0):

initMocks should not be called from your tests. Not sure why you are using PowerMockito, I assume Mockito is the usual choice to go. Remove the 3 annotations on ThingTest class.

If you use JUnit4, take a look at @Rule and the Mockito.rule(), eg.

```
 @Rule
  public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule()
```

Edit: I assume there is some other critical problem, the Thing 't' does not have the tp or the tgpp set, it will create new objects instead, these are not mocks.

Make sure that Thing t is properly initialized for spy. Perhaps you should add to setup: `when(t.fun(anyInt()).thenReturn(tgpp)`?

Comment: I'm going to mock static method somewhere in my tests, so I've those 3 annotations. I didn't quite get why to use @Rule. PS: Found that `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);` can be used to initialise the mocks. Although, things didn't solve for me.

Comment: I added `doReturn(tgpp).when(t).fun(anyInt()); when(tgpp.GpFun(anyInt())).thenReturn(tp); when(tp.fetchSideThing()).thenReturn(st);`. but it throws `Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.amazon.configurationeditor.store.ThingGrandParent$MockitoMock$1721026741.toString()`

Comment: To make your testing run you do not use static mocking anywhere. So removing PowerMockito overhead and follow instructions would be wise. Static mocking is usually to be avoided, it is indication of weak design. If you want to solve a different problem as the one described, just pose a new different question. Thank you.